# Generating Embed Token, all data is returned

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

***To embed report into my app, I generated an Embed Token using Embed Token API***

```
 public EmbedToken GetEmbedToken(Guid reportId, IList<Guid> datasetIds, [Optional] Guid targetWorkspaceId)
        {
            PowerBIClient pbiClient = this.GetPowerBIClient();
    
            var rlsIdentity = new EffectiveIdentity(
                datasets: new List<string>{ datasetId.ToString()}
            );
           
            var tokenRequest = new GenerateTokenRequestV2(
                reports: new List<GenerateTokenRequestV2Report>() { new GenerateTokenRequestV2Report(reportId) },
                datasets: datasetIds.Select(datasetId => new GenerateTokenRequestV2Dataset(datasetId.ToString())).ToList(),
                targetWorkspaces: targetWorkspaceId != Guid.Empty ? new List<GenerateTokenRequestV2TargetWorkspace>() { new GenerateTokenRequestV2TargetWorkspace(targetWorkspaceId) } : null,
                identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity> { rlsIdentity }
            );
    
            // Generate an embed token
            var embedToken = pbiClient.EmbedToken.GenerateToken(tokenRequest);
    
            return embedToken;
        }
```

Token Generation is successful but all the data is returned and not sure what happened.
Any idea about what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to provide a username and a role when we are generating Embed Token. If not for service principal, token generation will fail and for master user although Token Generation will succeed but the data will not be filtered (all the data is returned).

```
  // Defines the user identity and roles.
        var rlsIdentity = new EffectiveIdentity(
            username: "USERNAME",
            roles: new List<string>{ "ROLES" },
            datasets: new List<string>{ datasetId.ToString()}
        );
```

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/cloud-rls